# How to control framerate of encoded data inside uridecodebin?

Tags: gstreamer

Im using `uridecodebin` with multiple types of sources, rtsp, http, filesrc, etc. But I want to control framerate at which frames are decoded, for example decode only 1 frame every 60 frames. I can set plugin that changes framerate after `uridecodebin`, but it will change framerate of already decoded frames(drop them).

May be there is some element that autodetects the source element, that I can connect to `decodebin`? I found [autovideosrc](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/autodetect/autovideosrc.html?gi-language=c), but I dont understand how to use it. Any advise appreciated.